# How to create a row without losing the column names, for input of row_to_json?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to use the `row_to_json(row)` function to create a JSON object in the database directly. This works as expected:

```
select row_to_json(country) from country
```

It returns something like:

```
[
    {"identifier": 1234, "name": "US"},
    {"identifier": 5678, "name": "France"},
    ....
]
```

However, when manually creating a row, I lose the column names. For example, the following query:

```
select row_to_json(row(country.identifier, country.name)) from country
```

gives:

```
[
    {"f1": 1234, "f2": "US"},
    {"f1": 5678, "f2": "France"},
    ....
]
```

This construct loses the column names. I need these column names in my output.

I found one solution:

```
with country as (select identifier, name from country)
select row_to_json(country) from country
```

Is there a way to do this directly - that is, without a CTE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a derived table:

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
  select identifier, name 
  from country
) t
```

Or you can use json_build_object() but that would require repeating the column names:

```
select json_build_object('identifier', identifier, 'name', name)
from country
```

Comment: I hoped there was something less clumsy or repetitive... too bad. Thanks for the alternatives!

Comment: do we know if this has evolved since 2017?